# WSO2 API Manager - Specify port number of HTTP/S Endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm creating an entry in API Manager for one of our webservice endpoint which doesn't use the default HTTPS port of 443, it's binded to port 444 at the moment.

I'm configuring this API entry in WSO2 AM to be accessible via HTTPS only but I can't get it to work. I've entered https://:444/ as the HTTP Endpoint  value when creating the API record.

Has anybody successfully setup a similar scenario? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "I can't get it to work"? Do you get any errors?

Comment: PLs explain this.  "I'm configuring this API entry in WSO2 AM to be accessible via HTTPS only but I can't get it to work. I've entered https://:444/ as the HTTP Endpoint value when creating the API record."

Comment: my endpoint that I'm trying to setup in API Manager is at https://website.com:444

The error that I get is a request timeout.

Comment: You can try few things. First try to check connectivity from API Manager deployed node to website.com:444 and see if that connection works fine. And even if it work enable API Manager wire logs and see what actually outgoing URL looks like(http://suhan-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-get-wire-logs-from-wso2-esb.html).